# Matrix Computation: Why is two for loop faster than one for matrix*vector

Tags: performance, julia

I am trying to test the time elapsed and speed up of using for loops vs. vectorized operations for a matrix * vector. My code works as intended however, unexpectedly to me, method 2 was the slowest.

My question is why is method 2 slower than method 1? With two for loops and more array indexing, I would expect it to be the slowest.

Code:

```
using LinearAlgebra
function matrix_vector()
    n = 10000

    A = rand(Float64, (n,n))
    x = rand(Float64, (n))
    b = zeros(n)
    bb = zeros(n)

    # Method 1
    t1 = @elapsed begin
        for i in range(1,n)
            for j in range(1,n)
                b[i] = b[i] + A[i,j]*x[j]
            end
        end
    end

    # Method 2
    t2 = @elapsed begin
        for i in range(1,n)
            bb[i] = A[i,:]'x
        end
    end

    # Method 3
    t3 = @elapsed begin
        bbb = A*x
    end

    println("Method 1 Time: ", t1)
    println("Method 2 Time: ", t2)
    println("Method 3 Time: ", t3, "\n")

    println("Speedup1: ", t1/t2)
    println("Speedup2: ", t2/t3)
    println("Speedup3: ", t1/t3)
    
end    

matrix_vector()
```

Sample output:

```
Method 1 Time: 0.723233
Method 2 Time: 1.0166901
Method 3 Time: 0.0235032

Speedup1: 0.7113603250390655
Speedup2: 43.25751812519146
Speedup3: 30.771682153919468
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In method 2, you construct a new `Vector`, `A[i, :]` every iteration of the loop.**

The slicing expression `A[i, :]` is allocating (it allocates memory on the heap), but `A[i, j]` does not. Effectively, `A[i, :]` is making a new `Vector`. Allocation is a relatively expensive operation, and this is the cause of the slowdown you are seeing.

But in your method 2 it isn't necessary to allocate anything. To avoid allocation and still use the slicing syntax, you can use the [`@view`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)) macro:

```
t2 = @elapsed begin
    for i in range(1,n)
        bb[i] = (@view A[i,:])'x
    end
end
```

Which produces output where method 2 beats method 1, as expected:

```
Method 1 Time: 0.275012702
Method 2 Time: 0.165204481
Method 3 Time: 0.039597826

Speedup1: 1.6646806450728175
Speedup2: 4.172059370128046
Speedup3: 6.945146483546849
```

Comment: You say "in your method 2 it is necessary to allocate anything"; you mean "it isn't necessary".